# Xamarin-Forms - Listview expansiva

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms, visual-studio-2017

Tenho um banco de dados para criação de um cardápio, neste tenho três tabelas:
1 - Tipos do cardápio
2 - Grupos do cardápio
3 - Opções do cardápio

Este banco de dados será atualizado e consultado por uma WEB API que já foi desenvolvida em ASP.NET CORE, ou seja, já esta rodando. Agora estou modelando um aplicativo e gostaria de saber se com o Xamarin Forms é possível criar uma listview que exiba as opções agrupadas de acordo com as informações de cada tabela e só exiba a lista completa ao tocar em um dos tipos de cardápio. Por exemplo:

**REFEIÇÕES (tabela 1 - tipos do cardápio)**
SELF (tabela 2 - grupos do cardápio)
*SELF-SERVICE (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*

PRATOS DO DIA (tabela 2 - grupos do cardápio)
*SEGUNDA - VIRADO A PAULISTA (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*
*TERÇA - BIFE/FRANGO A PARMEGIANA (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*
*QUARTA - FEIJOADA (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*
*QUINTA - LASANHA (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*
*SEXTA - PEIXE COM PURÊ (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*

**BEBIDAS (tabela 1 - tipos do cardápio)**
REFRIGERANTES (tabela 2 - grupos do cardápio)
*REFRIGERANTE LATA (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*
*REFRIGERANTE 1,5L (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*

SUCOS (tabela 2 - grupos do cardápio)
*SUCO NATURAL (COPO) (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*
*SUCO NATURAL (JARRA) (tabela 3 - opções do cardápio)*

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda.

Classes que uso na API:

```
public class TipoCardapio
{
    [Key]
    public int TipoId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GruposDoCardapio> GruposDoCardapios { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OpcoesDoCardapio> OpcoesDoCardapios { get; set; }

}

public class GruposDoCardapio
{
    [Key]
    public int GrupoId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Notas { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoCardapio TipoCardapios { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OpcoesDoCardapio> OpcoesDoCardapios { get; set; }
}

public class OpcoesDoCardapio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(11)]
    public string DiaDaSemana { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(35)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoCardapio TipoCardapios { get; set; }
    public virtual GruposDoCardapio GruposDoCardapios { get; set; }

}
```

Imagens:
[image: Modelo 1 - Cardápio]

[image: Modelo 2 - Cardápio]

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a expandable listview seja o que você quer.
Veja esse [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-expendable-listview-app/) e positive caso te ajude.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @BrianSouza ... Vou dar uma olhada no material do link, analisar o código e buscar a melhor maneira de adaptar a minha necessidade.

Comment: Se alguém mais estiver a procura, achei este [link](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/ExpandableView) interessante.